# Wordpress. make a custom post type layout

Tags: wordpress, layout, tabs, custom-post-type

I know how to create a custom post type in Wordpress. But how can I set a layout or design of this post type?

I want to have a title, below should be a picture. Then 2 tabs. Each with different content.
See screenshot:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: you can create a single-$posttype.php . Look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dave, I go with WordPress terminology: page = type of post called "page" & controlled by "page.php". "post" = controlled by "single.php". Custom post type = controlled by "single-yourposttype.php" (for example "single-videos.php" if your custom post type is "videos"). I suppose you want all custom posts of one type to be displayed this way, not just one single post (otherwise, there would be no point). So this is exactly what I explained how to do in my previous answer. 
For the tabs, you just have to create a tab system (maybe like http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) and adapt your template (again, your template will be single-nameofyourposttype.php). If you have prepared metaboxes to save the content for each tab in two different fields, you will use `get_post_meta()` (see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) to retrieve the contents for each tab. 
But maybe your difficulty is more so to prepare your custom post type admin before even worrying about displaying it. What you need is to create "meta boxes" (extra fields so you can enter different type of contents for your custom post type : here in this case: one text editor for each tab, with a possibility to upload photos, etc., just like the content area for a normal post). You can read more about creating meta boxes here : http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/
or here : http://thomasgriffinmedia.com/blog/2011/07/how-to-automatically-add-meta-boxes-to-custom-post-types/
It can look a bit overwhelming at first, but once you get the idea, everything is very easy and efficient.

Comment: another question: well for the first tab content I just want a description and a rating (could do with rating plugin). and if I click on second tab I want a google map to be display as content. so I can do this with metaboxes? Is that the right direction to go?

Comment: Yes it is. You could create a special metabox that instead of showing an editor, shows a Google maps and records the lat and long coordinates... This French guy has done it : http://wabeo.fr/blog/meta-box-coordonnees-gps/
Or check this : https://github.com/azagniotov/Comprehensive-Google-Map-Plugin/blob/master/metabox.php

Answer (score 2):

Get your single.php page in your theme. This page is used to produce the template for the normal posts pages. Save it under the name `single-yourposttype.php`. Change the content of this page to create your template, using `title()`, `content()`, exactly like in the `single.php` page for normal posts. If you need to get something to change in the header as well, call a different header for this post type by replacing `get_header();` with `get_header('posttype');` and create a modified version of `header.php` called `header-youposttype.php` which will be called when viewing your post type page.

Comment: I just want to customize the post, not the page, so I dont want to change the header. And how can I get the tabs for the post type? (see screenshot) I did not find a function for it on wordpress reference